# Need demo scripts and sample corrupted databases for corruption databases troubleshoot

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am looking for a demo for recovery of corruption databases in different ways.  Is there any link for those examples to practice in LAB machines.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the work by Steve Stedman. He has corruption examples for days, http://stevestedman.com/?s=corruption&submit=Go

Comment: I don't see any exact explanation of corruption of database.  It rooted me for registration for session.  I got the below URL for page level restore and it's cool with example.    https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/11/differences-offline-online-page-restores/

Comment: That's a great one too. Here is the full list of the corruption challenges http://stevestedman.com/server-health/database-corruption-challenge/ and how to create a corrupt database, http://stevestedman.com/2015/04/corruption-challenge-1-how-i-corrupted-the-database/

Answer (score 1):

Paul Randal (of the SqlSkills and `checkdb` fame) has a nice set of [pre-corrupted databases](https://www.sqlskills.com/sql-server-resources/sql-server-demos/) and instructions [how to work](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/conference-corruption-demo-scripts-and-example-corrupt-databases/) with those too.